# Node http-Server error

Tags: javascript, node.js, httpserver

I am following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I1USsIW8aWE at min 21:09 an http-server is called.

I have node installed on my windows box. I have also installed the http-server using npm.

When I try to run the server I get this error.

```
F:\Projects\LargeAppSpa\LargeAppSpa.FrontEnd
λ http-server src
C:\Users\Josh\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\http-server\bin\http-server:51
if (err) throw err;
               ^
Error: listen EACCES
at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1112:19)
at listen (net.js:1155:10)
at net.js:1253:9
at dns.js:85:18
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
at startup (node.js:129:16)
at node.js:814:3
```

Thinking this was a port problem I run this and it looks like it works...

```
F:\Projects\LargeAppSpa\LargeAppSpa.FrontEnd
λ http-server src -p1234
Starting up http-server, serving src on: http://0.0.0.0:1234
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

When I navigate my browser to this location I get a "page can not be displayed message".

Question 1) How can I use http-server without the port and use the default 8080?

Question 2) Why is this not working? What did I do wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: can you show your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usally, in Windows port 80 is probably tied up with IIS Server.
Try to stop iis first and after run your app again.

> Error: listen EACCES

Is basically saying it can't have access to the port

Please post your app code too...

Comment: Awesome iis was causing the problem. But why didn't it work in the browser when I defined the port number?

Comment: not sure - were there any errors in the console when you ran it and hit it in the browser?

Comment: :) it's all working now. so strange... anyways running iisreset /stop solved the problem with port 8080. I then ran iisreset /start and port 1234 started working again... go figure. Thanks for the help!